# Database Collation issue in commerce server 8.2.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I Have installed sitecore commerce server 8.2.1 experienced an error like below when loading the sitecore site
[image]

when I cheked the commerce server manager I noticed that the connection string of one of the partitions is incorrect, but when I try to save it I get the following error message.

[image]

can some one help me to solve this issue please?

*I didn't change the collation type of the database

Comment: It looks like there's a collation conflict between what Commerce Server expects and what your database is set to. If you Google that error, you will see lots of possible resolutions. Have you tried any of those yet?

Comment: Hi Dan,
I didn't change the collation type. I'm using working dbs in another environment. so I think the configuration changes should be done without changing the db properties

Comment: Yes, I know you didn't change the collation type. I think it was already set to something different than Commerce Server expects, judging by the error message you get.

Comment: What helped me, when I had that issue, was completly remove everything and set the db up again with the correct collation type. This was also sitecore recommendation for me.